# Deno keeps giving me the same type of error on different modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, jira, jira-rest-api, deno

I am trying to connect with the Jira REST api using Deno. My Library of choice is [Jira.js](https://deno.land/x/jira@v2.10.4). I've used both installing the node_modules locally and referencing the modules through the library link. To no avail, deno gives me the same type of error.

[image: error]

This is my code.

```
//import { Version2Client } from "./node_modules/jira.js/src/index.ts";

import * as jira from "https://deno.land/x/jira@v2.10.4/src/index.ts";


const client = new Version2Client({
  host: 'https://FFFFFF.atlassian.net',
  authentication: {
    basic: {
      email: 'FFFFFFF@gmail.com',
      apiToken: 'FFFFFFFF',
    },
  },
});


async function main() {
  const projects = await client.projects.getAllProjects();

  console.log(projects);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jira.js` [does not support Deno directly](https://github.com/MrRefactoring/jira.js/issues/241). But you can run it with [NPM compatibility](https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.1/node) mode, for that, you'll need to replace your import to use `npm:` specifier: `npm:jira.js`

```js
import { Version2Client } from 'npm:jira.js';

const client = new Version2Client({
  host: 'https://FFFFFF.atlassian.net',
  authentication: {
    basic: {
      email: 'FFFFFFF@gmail.com',
      apiToken: 'FFFFFFFF',
    },
  },
});

// ...
```

Comment: it works, but is it normal for ````const projects = await client.projects.getAllProjects(); ```` to return a web page? Shouldn't it return a JSON String?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `jira.js` check the documentation for it,